# PHP : how to accommodate the data containing the symbols of the database into an array json?

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatables, symbols

I want to display data from the column wo_wks_desc using json but there are some data that is not visible because the contents of the cel containing character symbol Ø, Ã, etc.

help me to solve this problem.

my code like that and to show json result i write the code in list_barcode2.php

```html
    <?php 
include "./class/connect_sql.class.php";
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) )
{


    
    $query = mssql_query("select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY barcode_wo_nmr) nomor, barcode_wo_nmr, barcode_wo_line,wo_wks_desc,
   barcode_wo_proses, barcode_npk, barcode_start, barcode_pending, barcode_end,barcode_qty,barcode_ng,barcode_reason_pending
   from WO_ENG_BARCODE, WO_ENG_DET, WO_ENG_DET_WKS  with(nolock) where 
   barcode_wo_nmr= WO_DET_NOMOR and barcode_line = wo_det_line  and barcode_wo_nmr = wo_wks_nmr and 
   WO_DET_NOMOR = wo_wks_nmr and barcode_wo_line = wo_wks_line and WO_DET_NAMA_BARANG = wo_wks_barang and right(barcode_wo_nmr,2) >= '15'
   order by barcode_wo_nmr desc");
    $jsonResult = '{"data" : [ ';
    $i=0;
    while ($data=mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
 {
       if($i != 0)
    {
           $jsonResult .=',';
       }
    
       $jsonResult .=json_encode($data);
    
    $i++;
  
   }
   $jsonResult .= ']}';
 
    echo $jsonResult;
} 
else {
    echo '<script>window.location="404.html"</script>';
}
?>
```

```html
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var table = jQuery('#dataTables').DataTable( {
                    "ajax": "./pc_list_barcode.php",
                    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "nomor" },
                        { "data": "barcode_wo_nmr" },
      { "data": "barcode_wo_line" },
      { "data": "wo_wks_desc" },
                       
      
      { "data": "barcode_wo_proses" },
      { "data": "barcode_npk" },
      { "data": "barcode_start",
       "width": "120px"
      },
      { "data": "barcode_pending" },
      { "data": "barcode_end" },
      { "data": "barcode_qty" },
      { "data": "barcode_ng" },
      { "data": "barcode_reason_pending",
       "width": "120px"
       },
      {
       "data": "barcode_wo_nmr",
       "render": function(data){
        return '<font color="blue"><a href="edit_barcode.php?id=' + data + '">EDIT</a>' 
       }
      } 
      //{"data": "barcode_reason_pending"},
      // {"data": return '<a href="edit_barcode.php?id=' + row.id + '">EDIT</a>' },
                    ]
                } );
```

Comment: dont try like this, please try like json_encode(array("data"=>$complete_data)), where $complete_data is array containing all the fetched records

Comment: Is it like this ?  while json_encode($data=mssql_fetch_assoc($query))

Comment: no, get all the records in one array, and then do the json_encode on that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$rows = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $data;
}

$jsonResult = json_encode(array(
    "data" => $rows
));
```

And in order to get all the symbols encoded properly you need to tell mysql before executing the query that you want your data encoded in UTF-8, like this:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8')
```